# SQL data export issue : The code page on input column is 65001 and is required to be 1252

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, ssis

I have an issue while exporting data to UTF-8 format from SQL server 2005.

Below is my query and error. Kindly help me with this.

```
select distinct 
    a.column1,
    a.column2,
    a.column3,
    a.column4,
    a.column3 
from 
    table1 a, 
    table2 b 
where 
    a.column1 = b.column1;
```

> Error: Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task: The code page on input column
>   "column3" (50) is 65001 and is required to be 1252. (SQL Server
>   Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task: The code page on input column "column4" (53) is 65001 and is required to be 1252. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004706b: Data Flow Task: "component "Destination - test1_txt" (37)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc004700c: Data Flow Task: One or more component failed validation.   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)   Error 0xc0024107: Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Column3 and column4 are of type char. Remaining are of type varchar.

Kindly help me with this. I also tried converting them but getting the same error.

```
convert(varchar(50),a.column3) as column3.
```

> Error 0xc00470d4: Data Flow Task: The code page on input column "column3" (64) is 65001 and is required to be 1252".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to have to use -C 65001 and CODEPAGE = 65001. SQL Server defaults for US English installs to code page 1252.